# Java string randomly replace character with latin char

Tags: java, postgresql, unicode

I'm creating a program with Java to move some data in PostgreSQL table to another table. Every time the program reads a row, it will store the data in an SQL query, which is stored in a String object.

The data will be inserted after every 500 rows read. The problem I have is that sometimes a char in the String got replaced randomly with latin characters such as ȶ, Ȭ, ǎ, etc, which caused error when it was queried into the database. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Reading + Writing the query:**

```
        dat = statement.getResultSet(); //grabbing the data
        int index = 0;
        while(dat.next())
        {
            if(index == 0 || index%500 == 0)                                  //check if it's the start of data or already 500 rows read
                { 
                    if(index > 0) 
                    {                      
                        stm = stm.substring(0, stm.length()-2);               // removing the space and comma at the end of final data
                        sql = new String(stm.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");     // this is my attempt at trying to remove the latin char..
                        statementUnified.execute(sql);
                    }
                    stm = "INSERT INTO table (data_source_id, is_deleted_flag,"+columnlist+") values ");
                }

                stm = stm.concat(" ("+sourceid+",\'0\'");
                for(int i = 0;i<columnsize;i++)
                {
                    stm = stm.concat(",");
                    temp = dat.getString(columnlist.get(i));          //grabbing the data based on the column name
                    if(temp != null)                                                     //replacing escaped char in java and postgresql and removing leading / trailing whitespaces 
                    {
                        temp = temp.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
                        temp = temp.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\\\"");
                        temp = temp.replaceAll("\'", "\'\'");
                        temp = temp.replaceAll("%", "%%");
                        temp = temp.trim();
                    }

                    if(temp == null) stm = stm.concat("NULL");               // if data from table or after trimming the whitespaces is NULL, then append NULL to query
                    // after this there are some validation for email, gender, date of birth, etc.
                    else                   //if validation goes well, then the program will go into this ELSE
                    {
                        stm = stm.concat("\'"+temp+"\'");                      //inserting the data into query
                    }
                }
                stm = stm.concat(") , ");
                index++;
        }

        if(stm.endsWith(" , "))                                      //if the final query didn't reach 500 rows
        {
            stm = stm.substring(0, stm.length()-2);
                sql = new String(stm.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
                statementUnified.execute(sql);
        }
```

Comment: Likely an encoding issue.

Comment: Check the encoding settings in your database and everywhere where you "change environment", e.g. Client-/Server-Comms, DB Connection retrieval etc. The conversion is happening somewhere there, not in the JVM itself.

Comment: @Ray I checked the encoding for the databases, and they're in UTF-8.

Comment: @Ray I don't really understand about the "change environment"... but the way i ran the query to the database is by using postgresql jdbc driver.

Comment: Can you explain (show code) what you mean by "store data in an SQL query" when you read? Show how you read and how you write.

Comment: @RealSkeptic updated the question with my code :)

Comment: This kind of query is a really bad idea. You should be using prepared statements with `addBatch` and not playing around with the string. Better yet, if you're not doing anything with the data in Java, use a direct INSERT... SELECT with just the data_source_id, is_deleted_flag coming from Java.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i've never used PreparedStatement or addBatch before, so i'll look into that and fix my code. but is it the one that cause the latin character appearing in the string?

Comment: I think one of the string replacements you are doing on the resulting string is the cause of that - or the non-ASCII character already exists in database. It's hard to say.